# Is any subspace of a weak Hausdorff space necessarily weak Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

As the title suggests, is any subspace of a weak Hausdorff space necessarily weak Hausdorff. Thanks.

Comment: For those not familiar with the concept, a space $X$ is weakly Hausdorff if $f[K]$ is closed in $X$ whenever $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and $f:K\to X$ is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is weakly Hausdorff, and $Y\subseteq X$. Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $f:K\to Y$ be continuous. Then $f$ can equally well be viewed as a continuous map of $K$ into $X$, so $f[K]$ is closed in $X$, and $f[K]=f[K]\cap Y$ is closed in $Y$. Weak Hausdorffness is therefore hereditary.